# Weird behavior of PolyLog

Tags: special-functions, complex, summation

I have asked *Mathematica* (11.1.0.0) to calculate

```
Sum[Log[n]/n (-9/10)^n, {n, 2, ∞}]
```

This is the sum $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\limits\frac{\log n}{n}\left(-\frac{9}{10}\right)^n$ which is of course a real number. I get the result $-\text{PolyLog}^{(1,0)}\left(1,-\frac{9}{10}\right)$ which in full form is

```
Times[-1,Derivative[1,0][PolyLog][1,Rational[-9,10]]]
```

I'm not much of expert on polylogs but if this is the result Mathematica gives for a real convergent sum, I expect that it must be real. But Mathematica reports that it has a nonzero imaginary value:

```
Im[Times[-1, Derivative[1, 0][PolyLog][1, Rational[-9, 10]]]] < 0
```

Returns `True`.

To make things worse, the result is not consistent. Sometimes it reports the the imaginary value is negative. After I restart the kernel or do some calculations it says the value is positive. (But I haven't yet seen it claim the value is 0, as it should be).

Things are also getting interesting when I try to evaluate numerically with custom precision. Here are some results:

```
N[Im[Times[-1, Derivative[1, 0][PolyLog][1, Rational[-9, 10]]]], 20]
-7.8182882575173819075*10^-7

N[Im[Times[-1, Derivative[1, 0][PolyLog][1, Rational[-9, 10]]]], 30]
2.54606310309014286041520864377*10^-7

N[Im[Times[-1, Derivative[1, 0][PolyLog][1, Rational[-9, 10]]]], 40]
5.969270870099067777121383351013126016958*10^-8
```

Despite not reporting any loss of precision, the evaluations give widely varying results (which are all way off, if we assume the correct value is 0).

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: I wouldn't call them widely varying. I would say they're slowly converging to zero.  I would call it a bug, even if it's a very hard computation. It's not doing what `N` says it does (with respect to the accuracy of the result).  The real part is converging slowly, too.  Much easier to sum the first few hundred terms at high precision.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thanks. Should I report this to Wolfram? If so, how should I present this in a way that will convince them it's a bug?

Comment: `NSum[Log[n]/n (-9/10)^n, {n, 2, \[Infinity]}]` returns no imaginary part.